# How to add PATH to $PATH variable in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I kept trying adding a path to my variable path using the export..
But when I close the Terminal and open a new one I find that the PATH is not added.

How can I add it to be generic for all sessions ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show how you define it. Should be something like `PATH=$PATH:/new/dir` in your `~/.profile`.

Comment: @fedorqui unless you're using OSX, it should be in `~/.bashrc` not `~/.profile`.  `~/.profile` is only read by login shells.

Comment: @terdon so `~/.bashrc` is loaded always? although the login is visual, not shell one?

Comment: @fedorqui it will be loaded every time you open a terminal. `~/.profile` is ignored unless you run a login shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you close the terminal, whatever changes you made to the environment are lost the next time you open it. All `export` does is, it **retains** the environment changes you made in the current shell so that if you *spawn* a new subshell (by running bash or otherwise).

If you want these changes to persist across sessions, you can add that `export` command to a login file, like `.login` or `.bashrc`

Comment: Can you clarify more how can I change that in .login or .bashrc ?!!

Comment: Well, you just need to edit your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.login` to add the line where you exported your command. [Read more](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)